# very quick issue about php in assigning variable

Tags: php, mysql

i have this quick issue

i want to add a number 1 before the $_POST[];

```
$fileName = "1"'.$_POST['name'].'"";
```

what am i doing wrong? because it's not giving me any result! Thanks!
ps.i know the question is dumb...

Comment: You begin a second string with `'` without using the concatenation operator (`.`).

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
$fileName = "1" . $_POST['name'];
```

Or

```
$fileName = "1 {$_POST['name']}";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this...

```
$fileName = "1".$_POST['name'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use either of the following:

```
$fileName = '1' . $_POST['name'];
```

or

```
$fileName = "1" . $_POST['name'];
```

or

```
$fileName = "1{$_POST['name']}";
```